# Enabling Elasticsearch _size field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with over 9,000,000 docs.

I have defined my own mapping and everything went fine.

The only problem is that I forgot to enable the _size field and now I need it to localize document with a large size.

From the documentation I found that it's just fine to use the PUT mapping API with these parameters:

```
{
    "my_index": {
        "_size": {
            "enabled": true
        }
    }
}
```

- Does the new mapping will be merged with the one already set?
- Does the size field will be enabled for already stored documents?

I am a little worried making changes to mapping beacuse the last time that I have updated the settings with a new analyzer the service was having problem due to shard relocation and everything got stuck.

Comment: Could you provide the whole query (e.g. curl version)? Unfortunatelly, I can't repeat it

Comment: Val answered my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45269524/enable-size-for-exist-index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mappings will be merged OK and the `_size` field will be enabled for all your documents of type `my_index`.

Note that if you want to store the `_size` (in addition to just index its value), you also need to add `"store": "yes"` in your `_size` mapping.

Unfortunately, you'll need to re-index your data in order for the `_size` field to be properly indexed.

Comment: And `_size` feature is going to [change in 2.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/_removed_features.html#_literal__size_literal_is_now_a_plugin) and moved outside core ES and into a plugin instead.