# Enable _size for exist index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I need to enable ["_size"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/mapper-size-usage.html) for an exist index. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33121095/enabling-elasticsearch-size-field) talks that it's possible. But it provides no example how to do it.

According to ["Put Mapping API"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) I executed query

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/my_index/_mapping/my_type?pretty" -d '{
      "properties": {
        "_size": {
          "enabled": true,
          "store" : true
        }
    }
}'
```

and got error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "No type specified for field [_size]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "No type specified for field [_size]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

What my mistake is? Please, show the correct version of this query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to install the [mapper-size plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/5.5/mapper-size.html):

```
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install mapper-size
```

Then you'll be able to enable it like this:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "_size": {
        "enabled": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
PUT my_index/_mapping/my_type
{
   "_size": {
     "enabled": true
   }
}
```

Comment: I am getting

`Field [_size] is defined both as an object and a field in [xxxx]`